# Python program compiled twice in a row

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just started to learn Python and encountered this problem as I was learning a bit of OOP.

I have two Python files in a package called students_database, on is Course:

```
import random
class course :

def __init__(self, name, initial_courses = []):
    self.course_name = name
    self.initial_courses = initial_courses
    self.ID = str(random.randint(0,9)) + str(random.randint(1000000, 9999999))
```

The latter is simply the **init** , generated with the package:

```
from students_database.Course import course

new_course = course("Algebra 1")
print(new_course.ID)
```

I've gathered that the problem lays in my import statement, but I don't understand what is my mistake, would love some help.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `class Course` ?

Comment: I don't know if it should, it was Course in the beginning and I've changed it to see if it's somehow related to the problem, it isn't. C or c, it works the same.

Comment: what is your problem exactly???

Comment: watch out for that mutable default argument...

Answer (score 0):

as I understand it should be something similar to: from  import 
Probably it helps you e.g to write Filenames in lower cases und classes in UPPER and functions in camel case greets

---

EDIT

---

I would suggest to addopt the code such way:

```
from course import COURSE

new_course = COURSE("Algebra 1")
print(new_course.ID)
```

and the ohter file:

```
import random

class COURSE :
    def __init__(self, name, initial_courses = []):
        self.course_name = name
        self.initial_courses = initial_courses
        self.ID = str(random.randint(0,9)) + str(random.randint(1000000, 9999999))
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer, how do you suggest to fix it?

Comment: sorry for missunderstanding readings...- I would suggest 2 things =>a) come to a convinient declaration meaning name all your files with small letters and CLASSES with UPPER Letters and Funtions in CamelCase way so you are able to recognise what you are accessing =>b) check your import statement like ( from Course import course ) then it works fine ;)              possibly i missunderstood the questions

Comment: @MichaelLehrach , a code style convention already exists in Python, it is [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and has a dedicated section about [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions).